# Twinkling Star Background Error - HTML5 Canvas and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have some Javascript code to paint a bunch of stars on a `<canvas>` and make them twinkle as well, but my code isn't working at all.

What happens is that the stars all just start out at full opacity (save for a few which fade-in and then remain at full opacity). I don't know why the opacity isn't going back down as I thought I had programmed in the `incrementOpcity()` method in the `Star` class.

I tried to use an object to represent a star, but I'm not sure if I had implemented it correctly. I also don't know if I'm using the `<canvas>` context wrong.

Can anyone tell me exactly what the problem is?

**The code can be found [here](http://tinkerbin.com/SjIY8G2G)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major problem is that you were drawing boxes of different opacity over each other, without removing the old box. As a result, you eventually it just looked like a singular white box showing..

You also had two bugs that I fixed up.

You can see my changes here: http://tinkerbin.com/ZfAxYXVs

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [updated one](http://tinkerbin.com/kqFEBlos).

Main problems:

1. You need to clear the canvas and redraw your black background each frame.
2. You were accessing the `opacity` variable in `fillStyle`, where it should be `this.opacity`.
3. Your bound checking was not quite working.